# Firebase Resize images extension always showing filename as _200x200 not as filename_200x200

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-extensions

I am using firebase resize image extension in my android app first time. I have selected the dimension of 200x200 image size. But in the firebase storage a new filename is not getting created with filename having suffix of 200x200. Its always creating the filename as _200x200 only. so images are getting override all the time. 
I have installed the firebase resize image extension in firebase console side only, no firebase function is included into my android studio code.

```
 if (filepath!= null){
            storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
            storageReference = storage.getReference();
            StorageReference ref = storageReference.child(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            ref.putFile(filepath)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Image added successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
```

[image: Firbase storage image]

Answer (score 0):

Since extensions are configured through the Firebase console, it's unlikely (thuogh not impossible) that this code is the cause of the problem.

This type of problem is typically better filed at the [Firebase Extensions repo](https://github.com/firebase/extensions).

In this case it looks like some folks already did file the issue: https://github.com/firebase/extensions/issues/130 I recommend tracking the status of that bug for updates.